# how to set an unique id for link_to tag in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to separate unique ids for some linking purpose, I just want to know how to make an unique id for `link_to`?

Like I am using:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_question_path(question.id),method: :get, :remote => true, :id => @question.id%>
```

This didn't work then I tried:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_question_path(question.id),method: :get, :remote => true, id: myBtn_<%=question.id%> %>
```

Nothing worked. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', 
  edit_question_path(question.id),
  method: :get, 
  remote: true, 
  id: "myBtn_#{question.id}" %>
```

You need to see what's the way to access a question variable, as instance or local one (I used a `question`, as you're doing with the path), and `myBtn_<%=question.id%>` won't work if you don't have defined a `myBtn` variable, even less if you try to include erb tags to print inside the erb open-close for the `link_to`.

Comment: can you tell me how you edited that question like that preformatted one???

Comment: Using some markdown @Mayank, hit `ctrl-k` to make code blocks, there's also some hints how to use it.

Comment: Using some markdown @Mayank, hit `ctrl-k` to make code blocks, there's also some hints how to use it.